# Write to an existing pdf file and save it as a new file using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have a pdf file with some data in it. Now, I want to use this existing pdf file and insert a table into it. Then I want to save the file with a different file name so that the existing pdf file remains the same as it was before.

Note: the existing pdf file was not created using iTextSharp. it was randomly downloaded. I have to use the existing pdf file like a template.

```
public void Main(List<string> jobpath)
{

    string oldpath = @"C:\Files\sample_new.pdf";
    string newpath = @"C:\Files\sample_new_1.pdf";

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldpath);
    Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
    Document doc = new Document(size);

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(newpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
    doc.Open();

    foreach (var list in jobpath)
    {
        cb.BeginText();               
        doc.NewPage();
        doc.Open();               

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        table.TotalWidth = 400f;
        float[] widths = new float[] { 2f };
        table.SetWidths(widths);
        table.SpacingBefore = 40f;
        table.SpacingAfter = 30f;

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.Colspan = 3;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

        table.AddCell(list);

        doc.Add(table);

        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);                                          
    }
    doc.Close();
}
```

With the above code I am able to add the table, but the contents of the old file is not getting copied in the new file.

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your code with us.

Comment: @Ben I have shared the code

Answer (score -1):

With the following code I was able to add the content of an existing pdf into the new one. In this example only the first page was added.

```
string oldpath = @"C:\Files\sample_new.pdf";
string newpath = @"C:\Files\sample_new_1.pdf";

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldpath);
iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
Document doc = new Document(size);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(newpath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
doc.Open();

PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

foreach (var list in jobpath)
{
    doc.NewPage();
    doc.Open();                    

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    table.TotalWidth = 400f;
    float[] widths = new float[] { 2f };
    table.SetWidths(widths);
    table.SpacingBefore = 40f;
    table.SpacingAfter = 30f;

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.Colspan = 3;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    table.AddCell(list);
    doc.Add(table);
}
doc.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you adding the page of the existing document using `AddTemplate()`. That throws away all interactivity in the original document. You should use `PdfStamper` instead and `InsertPage()` to add the extra page. I'm temporarily down-voting your answer. Once you have fixed it so that it uses `PdfStamper`, let me know and I'll remove the down-vote (unless someone provides a more correct example in the meantime).